# How to retrieve all the name from MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to retrieve all the name and the number of row from MySQL to java. So far I only able to retrieve the total row number but I only get the last name. What's wrong here ?

**StaffManagement.java**

```
adminAPI api= new adminAPI();
try {
      int num= api.displayCheckBoxAndLabel();
      String allName= api.displayName();
      System.out.println(num+allName);
}
```

**adminAPI**

```
public int displayCheckBoxAndLabel() throws Exception // get the number of row 
    {
        int count = 0;
        String sql="Select count(*) AS adminID from admin";
        DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
         while(rs.next()) 
         {  
             count= rs.getInt("adminID");

         }
         ps.close();
         rs.close();
         conn.close();
         return count ;
    }

    public String displayName() throws Exception // get all the name 
    {
        String name = null;
        String sql="Select name from admin";
        DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
         while(rs.next()) 
         {  
             name= rs.getString("name");

         }
         ps.close();
         rs.close();
         conn.close();
         return name ;
    }
```

Comment: to retrieve all names use String[] names instead of String name; change your method return type to String[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently return a single `String`, and your method iterates all of the admin names (but terminates after the final row, so that's your result). Instead, build a `List` of names and return that. You could also use a [`try-with-resources` close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to `close` your `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` instances. Something like

```
public List<String> displayName() throws Exception // get all the name
{
    String sql = "Select name from admin";
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
    try (Connection conn = db.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            names.add(rs.getString("name"));
        }
    }
    return names;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful

```
private String names[];
int i = 0;

while (rs.next()) {
names[i] = rs.getString("name");
i++;
}
```

Then you can use a for loop to return each name in StaffManagement.java